# Rename [health-kit] to [healthkit]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

This is a proposal to rename [health-kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/health-kit) to [healthkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/healthkit), for homogeneity with [uikit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uikit), [cloudkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudkit), [researchkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/researchkit), etc.